# Equivalence between statements on linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Consider the integers $N,T,J$. In what follows, $I_N$ is the $N\times N$ identity matrix. $0_{N\times N}$ is the $N\times N$ zero matrix.

Let $A$ be an $NT\times (N+J)$ matrix structured as follows
$$
A\equiv \begin{pmatrix}
I_N & A_1\\
I_N & A_2\\
\vdots & \vdots\\
I_N & A_T
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where each of $A_1,...,A_T$ are $N\times J$ matrices.

Could you help to show that (or give me an informal intuition on why)

(1) The columns of $A$ are linearly independent if and only if the columns of
$$
B\equiv \begin{pmatrix}
I_N & A_1\\
0_{N\times N} & A_2-A_1\\
\vdots & \vdots\\
0_{N\times N} & A_T-A_1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
are linearly independent

(2) The columns of $A$ are linearly independent if and only if the columns of
$$
C\equiv \begin{pmatrix}
 A_2-A_1\\
\vdots \\
A_T-A_1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
are linearly independent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply doing row operations (in blocks), subtracting $[I_{N} \ A_{1}]$ from each block below it. Row operations don't effect the linear dependence/independence relations of the columns.

Once you do this, you can clearly see that there is a pivot position in each of the first $N$ columns. Any pivot position in the columns below that would correspond to a pivot position in
$$\begin{bmatrix} A_{2} - A_{1} \\ \vdots \\ A_{T} - A_{1}\end{bmatrix}.$$